# 'None' is being displayed in the output of quotient and remainder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Writing a program to print quotient and remainder, but everywhere change the quotientProblem function into one called quotientString that merely returns the string rather than printing the string directly. Have the main function print the result of each call to the quotientString function.

```
def value():
    a=int(input("Enter a number: "))
    b=int(input("Enter next number: "))
    z=print("When",a,"is divided by",b,"the remainder is",a%b,"and the quotient is",a//b,".")
    print (division(a,b,z))
def division(x,y,z):
    return z
value()
```

When I executed

```
>>>Enter a number: 5
>>>Enter next number: 3
When 5 is divided by 3 the remainder is 2 and the quotient is 1 .
None
```

Here `None` keeps displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the result of the `print` call to `z`. `print` has no specific return, which means it returns `None`. Your `division` function then prints that. Don't use the return value from `print`. I have no idea what you're expecting it to do, but initializing `z` to anything useful is not a possible outcome.

Comment: When 5 is divided by 3 the remainder is 2 and the quotient is 1 . I want this to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to happen? `division` is a function that takes three arguments and returns the last. So `division(a, b, z)` returns `z`. What is `z`? It's the return value of `print`. The `print` function returns `None`. So `division(a, b, z)` is `None`. And hence, your `print(division(a,b,z))` line prints `None`.

Comment: What would it be better to do?  All I want is  this to be displayed,  "When 5 is divided by 3 the remainder is 2 and the quotient is 1 ."

Comment: Just keep this:

`print("When",a,"is divided by",b,"the remainder is",a%b,"and the quotient is",a//b,".")`

Remove the `z = `, and remove the `print(division(a, b, z))`.

Comment: What about return? Do I have to use it or not? In order to eliminate z completely, I must not use it. But my scope was to display the output using return. How can I do it?

Comment: `return` does not display output. You can `return` a string, and then let `print` display the returned value.